# Is it possible to recover H2DB data after deleting data file?

Tags: database, local, h2, recovery

Is there any chance of recovering the data of an H2 database after having deleted the 'data' file? 
The other files are still present: 'index', 'log', 'trace'. I suppose not, but since I am not familiar with what's really stored in these other files, it might be there's a possibility you can tell me about.

Answer (score 0):

Usually not. The index file only contains the indexed columns, and the log file only the transaction log. The trace file is usually empty. But you can try what data is in those files, if you run the Recover tool.

Please note you are using a very old version of H2, because newer versions (starting from 2011) only use one database file (suffix `.h2.db`), and no longer user separate log and index files.